# How to systematically ignore image features (from a spatial light modulator)

Tags: image-processing

(I am unsure if this is the best Stack Exchange site for this question.  If not, please point me to the right one.)

I am generating light patterns with a device called a spatial light modulator (SLM).  I typically have a certain pattern that I want to generate, and after trying to implement the pattern with the SLM, I image it with a camera and compare to the desired pattern.  Here's an example of such an image, where the desired light pattern is a ring:

[image: Ring light pattern.]

I use, say, mean squared error between desired and observed light patterns to determine how good a job the SLM is doing.  The observed pattern deviates from the desired one in several ways:

1. There is always a bright spot (the "zero order spot") in the center of the image.
2. There is Poissonian noise from the camera.
3. There are systematic errors in the generated light pattern due to imperfections of the SLM.

**I am looking for ways to systematically ignore the first of these issues, the zero order spot,** in my comparisons of the actual and desired light patterns.  In some cases, like the image above, it is possible to do so by simply zeroing out a region in the center of the image.  However, this is not a robust method, because sometimes there is overlap between the zero order spot and the desired pattern, as in the image below.

[image: A light pattern overlapping with the zero order spot.]

Properties of the zero order spot that I can quantify are its rough size and location.  The pixels at the center of the spot are typically completely saturated (this is the only saturated part of the image); consequently the relative amplitude of the spot depends on the exposure of the camera, and so is not stable across multiple pictures.

**What are methods to systematically ignore this spot in my analysis of these images?**  (I am deliberately phrasing this question in a somewhat open-ended way, as I am interested in all relevant techniques.  I am a non-expert in image processing.)